# I can't send form input values to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my index.php I am trying to login and I have to get input values. Then I am sending to Memberlogin.php controller using session.

In index.php first lines

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.mydomain.com');
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
```

I am trying to get values like this

```
  <h2 style="text-align: center">Login Area</h2>
<table>
<form action="<?php echo site_url()."/Memberlogin/login";?>"method="post">
  <tr>
    <td>UserName</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="user_name" maxlength="20" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="20" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN!" /></td>
  </tr>
</form>
</table>
```

There is no syntax error.

Here is my Memberlogin.php controller

```
<?php 

ob_start();

ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.mydomain.com');

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');



class Memberlogin extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('session');
```

and here is my login function in Memberlogin.php

```
function login()
{
    $user_name  = $this->input->post('user_name', TRUE);
    $password   = $this->input->post('password', TRUE);


    if((!empty($user_name)) and (!empty($password)))
    {   ...
    }
```

But it is directly going to else which redirects to index.php

Comment: Try base_url instead of site url. On codeigniter config you can set cookie info instead of here ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.mydomain.com'); http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Comment: It didnt work. On the other hand even it is not detecting some php file about retrieving tweets which are in httpdocs.

Comment: `print_r($this->input->post());exit;` in controller and check what you are getting there

Answer (score 2):

do you already load the form helper?

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Comment: Yes I load helper('form'). Session is not working on live server. Project is working fine on localhost

Answer (score 0):

the action for your form is incorrect, replace it with this

```
action="<?php echo site_url('Memberlogin/login');?>"
```

also add the following in the form tag

enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('Memberlogin/login');?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

or use the url helper by doing this

Comment: It didn't work. Just going to else statement and redirecting to index.php

Comment: try doing a var_dump ($_POST); before the if statement

Comment: I am not getting any error. It is not getting the values and this why when it checks in if statement it passes to else statement. It works on localhost perfectly but on live server it is not working. Session is not working on live server I think. What should I do?

Comment: Again same result.. No progress.